# PropertyNotFoundException when calling valueChangeListner

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, propertynotfoundexception

I have the following simple selectOneMenu

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="shop" styleClass="tcell"
                 value="#{shoppingcenterControler.shoppingCenterScreenBean.shoppingcenterName}"
                 onchange="submit()"
                 valueChangeListener="#{shoppingcenterControler.shopChooseAction}">
  <f:selectItem itemValue="#{option.defaultShoppingcenter}" itemLabel="#{option.defaultShoppingcenter}"></f:selectItem>
  <f:selectItems value="#{shoppingCenterScreenBean.shoppingcenternames}"></f:selectItems>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

When I use `@Named` annotation on `shoppingcenterControler` I receive a `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException` warning me `Target Unreachable, identifier 'shoppingcenterControler' resolved to null`.

When I use `@ManagedBean` annotation I receive the warning: `Property 'shopChooseAction' not found on type com.manageMyShopping.presentation.controler.ShoppingcenterControler`, whlie `shopChooseAction` is not a property, it is:

```
public void shopChooseAction(ValueChangeEvent event){
    String shopName = getShoppingCenterScreenBean().getShoppingcenterName();
    if (!shopName.equals(defaultShopp)) {
        for (ShoppingCenterScreenBean thisShop : Shoppinglistcontroler.getShoppinglistScreenBean().getShoppingCentersScreenBean()) {
            if (!thisShop.getShoppingcenterName().equals(shopName)) {

                ShoppingCenterScreenBean newShoppingcenter = new ShoppingCenterScreenBean();
                newShoppingcenter.setShoppingcenterName(shopName);
                ShoppinglistScreenBean shoppinglist = Shoppinglistcontroler.getShoppinglistScreenBean();
                shoppinglist.getShoppingCentersScreenBean().add(newShoppingcenter); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have looked different links including the following:
[One somehow similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815358/propertynotfoundexception-when-using-beans-methods-result-for-hselectboolean)

However, it neither worked for me, nor I do like faked solutions. I am searching a real solution and I want to understand

1. Why `@Named` annotation is not functioning as it is expected? I have added the corresponding dependency to the `pom.xml` file of my project.
2. Why `valueChnageListener` should raise `PropertyNotFoundException` on the name of the method?

Any help is highly appreciated.

My environment: Fedora 24, Java 1.8, apache-tomcat 8.0.33, and I am using Eclipse Mars.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved my problem. Instead of using `valueChangeListener` as an attribute for the tag `<h:selectOneMenu>` I have used the tag    `<f:valueChangeListener>` as following:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="shop" styleClass="tcell"
                                value="#{shoppingcenterControler.shoppingCenterScreenBean.shoppingcenterName}"
                                onchange="submit()">
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="#{option.defaultShoppingcenter}" itemLabel="#{option.defaultShoppingcenter}"></f:selectItem>
                                <f:selectItems
                                    value="#{shoppingCenterScreenBean.shoppingcenternames}"></f:selectItems>
                                <f:valueChangeListener type="com.manageMyShopping.presentation.controler.ShoppingcenterListener"></f:valueChangeListener>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

and I have added the class *ShoppingcenterListener* as:

```
public class ShoppingcenterListener implements ValueChangeListener {

FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
String bundleName = "com.manageMyShopping.presentation.elementaryBeans.itemOptions";
Locale local = context.getViewRoot().getLocale();
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(bundleName, local);
String defaultShop = bundle.getString("defaultShoppingcenter");

@Override
public void processValueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {

    String shopName = event.getNewValue().toString();
    System.out.printf("ShoppingcenterNqme is: %s\n", shopName);
    if (!shopName.equals(defaultShop)) {
        for (ShoppingCenterScreenBean thisShop : Shoppinglistcontroler.getShoppinglistScreenBean().getShoppingCentersScreenBean()) {
            if (!thisShop.getShoppingcenterName().equals(shopName)) {

                ShoppingCenterScreenBean newShoppingcenter = new ShoppingCenterScreenBean();
                newShoppingcenter.setShoppingcenterName(shopName);
                ShoppinglistScreenBean shoppinglist = Shoppinglistcontroler.getShoppinglistScreenBean();
                shoppinglist.getShoppingCentersScreenBean().add(newShoppingcenter); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

and this solved my problem. Still I do not understand why the `@Named` annotation is not functioning as it is supposed.